# When is RMSprop Gradient Descent better than Momentum Gradient Descent

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, backpropagation, adam

Can you give an example where RMSprop is better than momentum?
In what cases does RMSprop (i.e. scaling $d\Theta_i$) help, but Momentum does not?

How is the combination of Momentum and RMSprop (i.e. Adam) improving sole Momentum (i.e. without RMSprop)? In cases where Adam is better than sole Momentum (i.e. without RMSprop), how is RMSprop contributing to the better results of Adam?

#### Line of thought

The weight updates in RMSprop gradient descent can be considered as normalizing a gradient $d\Theta_i$ by the factor $1/(\sqrt{Sd\Theta_i} + \epsilon)$. If $\nabla_\Theta J$ of the cost function $J$ points in the right direction, why should it be "distorted", i.e. $d\Theta_i$ be increased if it is small or decreased if it is large?

If $\nabla_\Theta J$ is not pointing in the right direction but causes divergence or oscillations, isn't momentum decreasing too large $d\Theta_i$ anyway? If $\nabla_\Theta J$ is pointing in the right direction but very small, isn't a larger learning rate solving the problem already? So isn't momentum with a suitable learning rate always better than RMSprop with a suitable learning rate?